# Printing from RDLC report to Dot Matrix Printer

Tags: printing, rdlc, dot-matrix

I am trying to print a RDLC report to a dot matrix printer using Generic/Text only printer driver in Windows XP.

But the problem is that,

- I am not getting the proper output as I am able to see in the preview
  of the report.
- In the print preview the report the output is perfect. But when I
  print to the printer, some of the fields are shrunk and not displayed
  completely.
- When I increase the width of the column in the table, its printing
  only some columns as it does not fit.

Comment: When you say "Preview", are you referring to the Print Preview of the ReportViewer control?  Or just the standard view of the reportViewer control?

Comment: Have you tried printing to other printers?  I have had difficult times getting the print functions to work properly with ReportViewer.  The screen rendering is always different than what comes out of the printer.